# hibernate fetch specific column from database using criteria

Tags: hibernate, criteria

I want to fetch specific column from database by using criteria.

select name, lastname from sssssss

Please reply

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

you need to use the projecttion Class.. check [this documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-projection) for details..

```
List results = session.createCriteria(SSSS.class)
    .setProjection( Projections.projectionList()
        .add( Projections.property("name") )
        .add( Projections.property("lastName") )
    )
    .list();
```