# Omit columns in Hibernate criteria queries

Tags: hibernate

I have a object Report with among many other columns a report_XML column with a big XML, its heavy to retrieve it each time and I want to somehow omit it from the result set. How can I do so?

My question is similar to these, but they don't answer the question fully. I know about Projections in Hibernate Criteria, but the problem with using them is that I in return get a list with object array, I want in return a list with objects of the given type the Criteria is made for, just with the fields I explicitly defined omitted, is that possible?

https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2410205

[hibernate fetch specific column from database using criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6715946/hibernate-fetch-specific-column-from-database-using-criteria)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hibernate allows making any property laoded lazily. For basic properties (such as our XML property), bytecode instrumentation is needed though. This is all described in [the documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html_single/#performance-fetching-lazyproperties).

So, if you mark this property as laz and execute your query, The XML property won't be loaded until you actually access the lazy property afterwards.